# How to define ahead vehicle in veins?

Tags: veins

I am using omnetpp 5.4.1, veins 4.7.1 and sumo-0.30.0. I want to define the vehicles that are ahead of other vehicles.
for instance I want that just ahead vehicle send message but behind vehicle only receive messages whose senders are ahead vehicles.
how can I do it I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

In a small simulation, you could simply note down the module ID of such vehicles and configure your application to only send messages if the ID is one of the special ones you wrote down.

In a large simulation, it is probably easier to think how a vehicle would determine its role in real life - e.g. based on exchanged messages - then implementing this mechanism in your simulation.